# Firestore in Cloud Functions: is documention deletion asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields) says that we can make use of the asynchronous aspect of deleting a document in "Java Android" (because there is a `onSuccessListener` we can deduce that). However, in "Node.JS" (so Cloud Functions), the sole line written is: `let deleteDoc = db.collection('cities').doc('DC').delete();`.

Does it mean it's not asynchronous for Node.JS or is the documentation simply not precise?

Comment: All Firebase APIs for node are asynchronous and return a promise.  The sample is just misleading because it assigns a variable that doesn't look like a promise.  Always click through to the API docs to see for sure.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson for your help, which is always very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs:

> `delete`
>
> `delete(): Promise<void>`
>
> Deletes the document referred to by this DocumentReference.
>
> `Returns Promise<void>`
>
> A Promise resolved once the document has been successfully deleted from the backend (Note that it won't resolve while you're offline).

You can find more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#delete